# Validation Message is not Displayed on View

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

This is not a repeated question am posting this question after trying all solutions.

I want to perform CRUD on a single View so I got this article

[CRUD using SIngle View](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bd8b0b/how-to-implement-insert-update-delete-functionality-in-singl/)

It works fine but when I keep the text box empty then the Model is Valid returns false which is correct,after debugging it shows Name field is required but I cant see the error on the View.

Even @Html.ValidationSummary(true) is present in Begin Form
and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)`

So keeping the code short have used only one field

Model

```
public partial class tblClient
{   
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A class which handle multiple button

```
public class HttpParamActionAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (actionName.Equals(methodInfo.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return true;

        var request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        return request[methodInfo.Name] != null;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class EmpController : Controller
{

    SampleEntities1 db = new SampleEntities1();  
    //
    // GET: /Emp/
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)  
    {  
        ViewBag.Operation = id;  
        ViewBag.Name = db.tblClients.ToList();  
        tblClient objEmp = db.tblClients.Find(id);  
        return View(objEmp);  
    }  

    [HttpPost]  
    [HttpParamAction]  
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]  
    public ActionResult Create(tblClient objEmp)   
    {  
        if (ModelState.IsValid)  
        {  
            db.tblClients.Add(objEmp);  
            db.SaveChanges();  
        }  
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }  

    [HttpPost]  
    [HttpParamAction]  
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]  
    public ActionResult Update(tblClient objEmp)  
    {  
        if (ModelState.IsValid)  
        {  
            db.Entry(objEmp).State = EntityState.Modified;  
            db.SaveChanges();  
        }  
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = 0 });  
    }  

    public ActionResult Delete(int id)  
    {  
        tblClient objEmp = db.tblClients.Find(id);  
        db.tblClients.Remove(objEmp);  
        db.SaveChanges();  
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = 0 });  
    }  
}
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
  {

<fieldset>
    <legend><b>Emp Details</b></legend>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>

            <th>
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<SingleVIewCrud.Models.tblClient>)ViewBag.Name)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Index", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</fieldset>

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <fieldset>
                <legend> <b>Entry Screen</b></legend>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" name="Create"
                               style=@((ViewBag.Operation != null && Convert.ToInt32(ViewBag.Operation) > 0) ? "display:none" : "display:block") />
                        <input type="submit" value="Update" name="Update"
                               style=@((ViewBag.Operation != null && Convert.ToInt32(ViewBag.Operation) > 0) ? "display:block" : "display:none") />
                    </p>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
}
```

What is wrong that the validation error message is not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both your `Create()` and `Edit()` POST methods, if `ModelState` is invalid, you just redirecting to the `Index()` view. You need to return the existing view -

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid()
{
    return View(objEmp);
}
// save and redirect
db.tblClients.Add(objEmp);  
db.SaveChanges();  
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Side note: If you include the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` scripts, then you will also get client side validation and the POST methods will not even be hit - the validation messages will be displayed and the submit will be cancelled

Comment: Hi, there is no Create and Edit View I have only one View which Is Index view as have to perform Create and Edit and display all on a single page.

Comment: Are your serious? But if that is the case, then its `return View("Index", objEmp);`

Comment: Yes Serious that's the requirement, cant use return View("Index", objEmp); as on Index View have to show all list of records which is coming from a ViewBag and in this case its null so it breaks.                 @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<SingleVIewCrud.Models.tblClient>)ViewBag.Name)

Comment: Tried return RedirectToAction("Index",objEmp); it returns the view but the validation message is not displayed. Searching how to use  jquery.validate.js as per your suggestion.

Comment: Because your taking the wrong approach - this is not the way to do it (and its a pity we cant down vote rubbish code in web sites like we do in SO). If you have included the relevant scripts, the validation messages will be displayed and the submit cancelled but that wont prevent malicious users from by passing client side validation.

Comment: You need a separate view for `Edit` and if you want to include a collection of existing items, then use `@Html.Action()` to call a controller method which returns a partial view of it. Or use a view model with a property for the collection and if `ModelState` is invalid repopulate the collection and return the view.

Comment: My requirement was different as I have to perform all on a single view after searching I got that URL so I thaught i can use it and it was working fine.

Comment: Currently learning how to use Jquery validation and then will  re create every thing using partial View. Initiallly I used ViewModels which included a list of records and single record but on Index used to get error as EF was expecting Key in ViewModel.

Comment: A view model has no relationship at all to EF (and it should be in a separate folder (say) ViewModels. You use EF to get and save your data models, but you map your data model to the view model, use that in the view and post it back, and then map the view model to the data model and save the data model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103157/discussion-between-dave-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: So Sorry. was thinking how to achieve it as I am totally confused and want to follow the correct approach

Comment: Can i have ur mail id.

Comment: Sorry, I don't give that out. (and you have started a chat room, so you should be adding further comments there)

Comment: I have created [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BfkEtV) as an example of the approach you can take